# What do we mean by speed of light dependent on direction?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, visible-light, waves, speed-of-light

I have a statement in textbook saying:

> When the speed of light is independent of direction, the secondary waves are spherical.

When is it dependent on direction and how will the secondary waves defer?

Comment: The first part about a sphere is just saying that when direction independent, light will travel in all directions with the same velocity. Because of this, it goes out in a sphere. If it was to propagate faster in the x direction, we would see this sphere become stretched in the x direction into an oblong. Directional dependence of light can occur in materials which are anisotropic (do not look the same in every direction).

Comment: @Tweej possibly true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some materials, called [`Birefringent`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birefringence) in which the index of refraction depends on the direction in which light is moving (often also dependence on the particular polarization of the light).  This is due to the crystallin structure of the material which allows faster propagation in one direction or another.

Another example would be a magnetized plasma where the magnetization means that the charged particles will respond different in-vs.-against the direction of the magnetic field, and thus propagating light rays will be affected differently.

[These are some really nice slides talking about both anisotropic plasmas, and crystals.](http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/beyersdorf/Archive/Phys208F07/ch%204-EM%20waves%20in%20anisotropic%20media.pdf)

Comment: Is that situation possible where speed of light is independent of direction but dependent on polarisation

Comment: @Sikander sure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer#Linear_polarizers